# i having trouble building expo app for iOS. Why can't i build the app for iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have an expo application and i'm trying to build the app for iOS. [image: error message]

I'm getting this error. Although I enter the right apple id and password. I still get the same thing over and over again.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work work this way.
Apple account is not enough, you need to create distribution certificate and development signing also.
For building iOS app, do it from Xcode. Details are given in apple developer documentation. Also you will not a get .app file, you will get a archive which will be used for distribution